# How do i parse HTML text with tags that i retrieve from firebaseDB in a TextView? No WebView

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, html-parsing

So I am trying to figure out how do i parse this HTML text with tags to a Textview in a List. Any good suggestions,is there a good library or maybe i should manually write code somehow to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options :

First is to use `Html.fromHtml(htmlString)`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else  {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
}
```

The tags allowed in this approach are : `<a href="...">
<b>,  <big>, <blockquote>, <br>, <cite>, <dfn>
<div align="...">,  <em>, <font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>,  <h2>, <h3>, <h4>,  <h5>, <h6>
<i>,  <img src="...">,  <p>, <small>
<strike>,  <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <tt>, <u>`

[Source](https://dzone.com/articles/how-display-html-android)

Another option is to use `CDATA`

Define a string resource like

```
<string name="stringName"><![CDATA[<html>%1$s</html>]]></string>
```

Then call it like `textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.stringName, htmlString));`

Comment: appreciate it. will test now

Comment: @Olehcoding If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct

Comment: sure thing fella!